# Storyline progression in SW:TOR

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I just saw that the Legacy in SW:TOR unlocks when a character finishes Chapter 1... level 26. I'm still not done with it.

How many chapters are there, and what is the level range of each? (on average)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 Chapters, along with a fairly long prologue.

Chapter 1 ends after you complete Alderaan. Chapter 2 ends after Hoth. Chapter 3 ends after Corellia. Level ranges will vary based on how much other content you complete.

Comment: Lets just say, the level of the last quest in the chapter.

Comment: In that case, 32 is the recommended level for the chapter 2 finale.

Comment: @Shadur I think you mean Chapter 1.

Comment: Ahh, yes. My bad.

Comment: I always do my class quests at their level, makes the class battles soooo much more fun (well, to me it's fun to fight a battle I can actually lose)